# Bind value to Kendo dropdown with Angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I create a kendo dropdown list and would like the list to have a value selected as specified from a $scope variable.

See the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BWGi8JYMSeh2JaLBmfPT?p=preview

I have tried using `k-ng-model` as well as `ng-model` but to no success.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your plunker, instead of specifying the entire object in your zzEventType, specify the id. So change:

```
$scope.zzEventType = {id:3, name:"PHP"};
```

To

```
$scope.zzEventType = 3;
```

It's been awhile since I used angular, but this works for me.

Comment: Thanks allot, i was looking for this solution for 3 hours now.